# cascading comboBox in windows form using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to Fill Combobox2 on combobox1 selectedText changed from the same table in windows form application. I am using sql serevr 2008 database. I am unable to fill combobox2 on combobox selected text changed.

Here is what i have tried:

```
private void Purchase_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fillName();
        comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = -1;

    }

   private void comboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBoxName.SelectedText != "")
        {
            fillMake();
        }


    }

   private void fillName()
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True");
       con.Open();
       string str = "Select Item_Name from Item";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
       SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
       DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
       adp.Fill(dtItem);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       comboBoxName.DataSource = dtItem;
       comboBoxName.DisplayMember = "Item_Name";
       comboBoxName.ValueMember = "Item_Make";


   }
    private void fillMake()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string str = "Select Item_Make from Item Where Item_Name='" + comboBoxName.SelectedText + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
        DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dtItem);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comboBoxName.DataSource = dtItem;
        comboBoxName.DisplayMember = "Item_Make";
        comboBoxName.ValueMember = "Item_Name";
        comboBoxName.SelectedIndex = -1;
        comboBoxName.Text = "Select";
    }
```

Sql server table for Items

```
Item_Code  Item_Name  Item_Make Item_Price UnitofMeasurement

           Cable        anchor  45.0000       meter
           Cable        polycab 30.0000       meter
           Button       anchor  15.0000       unit
           Button       havells 20.0000       unit
           Switch       cona    70.0000       unit
```

I have searched for solution but was unfortunate.
please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: please use SqlParameters to prevent from Sql injections.

Comment: thank you for suggestion sybren, i will keep in mind.

Comment: In fillName, you are not selecting Item_Make. You should also describe what isn't working in more detail.

Comment: Honestly just sort of casually saying you will keep parameters in mind is not good enough. Creating pass through sql like that is criminal. You must use parameters or better yet, stored procedures.

Comment: @SeanLange, it can be `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`, nothing criminal then. [Stored procedures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection.aspx) you say?

Comment: ROFL. Sure if you put a bunch of dynamic sql in your procedure you defeat the purpose. The point really is that coding style can and will be copied when it is a textbox. Do it the right way all the time and it saves a lot of headaches. Plus when you convert to procedures you can fix bugs on the sql side without redeploying the application. Layering your application makes your life so much easier.

Comment: I think you need to call `ComboBox.DataBind()` after you have assigned a DataSource. Also, is it intentional that you are repopulating the same combo box in both methods (`comboBoxName`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little difficult to figure out what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you are trying to populate a second combo box (`comboBoxMake`?) depending on what is selected in `comboBoxName`.  I am basing this answer on that assumption.  Apologies if I have this wrong.

There are lot of things that need attention in this code.  Let's look at `fillName()` first.

```
   private void fillName()
   {
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True");
       con.Open();
       string str = "Select Item_Name from Item";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
       SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
       DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
       adp.Fill(dtItem);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       comboBoxName.DataSource = dtItem;
       comboBoxName.DisplayMember = "Item_Name";
       comboBoxName.ValueMember = "Item_Make";
   }
```

You need to `Dispose()` your database objects.  This can be accomplished pretty cleanly with `using { .. }` blocks.

You don't need to manually open the connection; filling the table with the data adapter
does this automatically.

You don't need the call to `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

You should use the `SqlDataAdapter` constructor overload that takes a command object, since you have already manually created the command.

Finally, based on my assumption of your goal I have added a `distinct` to your query so it only gets the unique `Item_Name`s.

```
private void fillName()
{
    string str = "Select distinct Item_Name from Item";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dtItem);
                comboBoxName.DataSource = dtItem;
                comboBoxName.DisplayMember = "Item_Name";
                comboBoxName.ValueMember = "Item_Name";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On to `fillMake()`.  The same suggestions apply that I noted above.  Additionally:

Parameterize your SQL.  ***Parameterize your SQL***.  Not only is this far, far safer than concatenating your SQL together, it is much cleaner.  Seriously, read about SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

The `fillMake()` method in your original post seems to be repopulating `comboBoxName`.  Is this correct?  You mention two combo boxes but your code only references one.  I am assuming you mean to populate another combo box (`comboBoxMake`?) here:

```
private void fillMake()
{
    string str = "Select Item_Make from Item Where Item_Name = @item_name";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ashish-pc\;Initial Catalog=HMS;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", comboBoxName.Text);
            using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dtItem = new DataTable();
                adp.Fill(dtItem);
                comboBoxMake.DataSource = dtItem;
                comboBoxMake.DisplayMember = "Item_Make";
                comboBoxMake.ValueMember = "Item_Make";
                comboBoxMake.SelectedIndex = -1;
                comboBoxMake.Text = "Select";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, change the code in the event handler so it looks at the `Text` rather than the `SelectedText` property:

```
private void comboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxName.Text))  // Text instead of SelectedText
    {
        fillMake();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Slippery Pete for the solution. But still it does not populate or fill second combobox. please help!

Comment: @user2042290 Please show some sample data from the `Item` table.

Comment: i have edited the question, attached table for 'Item'

Comment: @user2042290 Thanks, your data looks as I imagined.  I have updated the answer with a small change to `comboBoxName_SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy, I deleted the SelectedIndexChanged event of Item_Name and rewritten it and it worked. thank you very much again