# Is there a way to pick up ID after cascading multiple combobox without using ID as value member of combobox?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I need to get productID from product table and pass it to a textbox. But I want to select the product ID by cascading comboBox texts as SQL query parameters.

I have tried cascading the comboBoxes. The cascading works fine and displays what I need.

I have done some research in cascading comboBox. Here are two useful links I have found out.

[cascading comboBox in windows form using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230874/cascading-combobox-in-windows-form-using-c-sharp)

[fill textbox on second combobox selection changed in cascading combobox in windows form using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333286/fill-textbox-on-second-combobox-selection-changed-in-cascading-combobox-in-windo)

In both links I did not find answer to my question.

Here is a demo table

```
ProductID Category                       SubCategory          Item
--------- ------------------------------ -------------------- ----------------
1         Pen                            Ballpoint            Matadoor
2         Pencil                         HB                   Natraz
```

I want get ProductID values by selecting Category, SubCategory, Item using cascaded comboBoxes.

Here is some demo code that takes care of the cascading.

1st ComboBox:

```
public InventroyAddForm()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
    string query1 = "select * from Product";
    string query2 = "select * from PartySpecificPrice";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
    //con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp.Fill(dt);
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "Category";
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Category";
    comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
    //con.Close();
    comboBox3.Enabled = false;
    comboBox4.Enabled = false;

}
```

2nd ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
   {
     string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
     string query1 = "select * from Product where Category=@Category";
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
     SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con);
     //con.Open();
     com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category",comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
     SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
     DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
     adp1.Fill(dt1);
     comboBox3.ValueMember = "Category";
     comboBox3.DisplayMember = "SubCategory";
     comboBox3.DataSource = dt1;
     comboBox3.Enabled = true;
     comboBox4.Enabled = false;
     //con.Close();
    }
}
```

3rd ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
    {
       string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
       string query2 = "select * from Product where Category=@Category";
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(maincon);
       SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
       //con.Open();
       com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString());
       SqlDataAdapter adp2 = new SqlDataAdapter(com2);
       DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
       adp2.Fill(dt2);
       comboBox4.ValueMember = "Category";
       comboBox4.DisplayMember = "Item";
       comboBox4.DataSource = dt2;
       comboBox3.Enabled = true;
       comboBox4.Enabled = true;
       //con.Close();
       textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(comboBox3.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are going to deal with `strings`(*which I would not recommend*) then why not create another query to fetch the `ProductID` from the `product` table with a `where` condition of `Category=<SomeCategoryValue> and SubCategory=<SomeSubCategoryValue> and Item=<SomeItemValue>;`

Comment: I would have but I need to fetch the ProductID and Products table will have a large number of data with many categories, subcategories and items. To offer a simpler way to select the ProductID cascading comboBox is the way to go in my opinion. Because to use your suggested query I have use either exact or approximate(using wildcards) SQL parameters value which is quite hard to do where the database has lots of products.``I would like to hear about your recommendation about not using strings `` @vikscool

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response,**1st** `As for why I would not recommend the String?` What if you have two `items` with the same name in different `subcategories` and the way you are getting the `items` it would be hard for you to identify which `item` belongs to which `subcategory`(*as your query is based on `Category` and not `Category+SubCategory`*).

Comment: **2nd** Your demo table looks like its a `Joined Result`. So, if you have other master tables for `Category` and `SubCategory`, it would be easier to make the cascading where the `item` table will have its parent `SubCategoryId` and the SubCategory would have its parent `CategoryId`. Hence, the relation would become something like this: `Category->get SubCategory based on the categoryId->get Items based on the subcategoryId`.

Comment: Thanks @vikscool. First of all your assumption of the table being join table is incorrect. The table i provided is in fact a single table. And you are suggesting to break up the table. But can I retrieve the product ID if I break up the table? if so can you post an answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @vikschool comments. I have broken up the tables as follows:

```
CID         Category
----------- --------------------------------------------------
          1 Pen
          2 Pencil


SID         CID         SubCategory
----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
          1           1 BallPoint
          2           2 HB


ID          SID         CID         Item
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------
          1           1           1 Matadoor
          2           2           2 Natraz


Category       SubCategory                                        Item
-------------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------------------
Pen            BallPoint                                          Matadoor
Pencil         HB                                                 Natraz
```

Here is the code that worked for me.

FormLoad:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string query2 = "select * from Category";
        string maincon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        adp1.Fill(dt1);
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CID";
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Category";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt1;
        comboBox3.Enabled = false;
        comboBox2.Enabled = false;

 }
```

First ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
       {

          string query2 = "select * from SubCategory where CID=@CID";
          SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
          com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
          SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
          DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
          adp1.Fill(dt1);
          comboBox2.ValueMember = "SID";
          comboBox2.DisplayMember = "SubCategory";
          comboBox2.DataSource = dt1;
          comboBox3.Enabled = false;
          comboBox2.Enabled = true;

       }
 }
```

Second ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      if (comboBox2.SelectedValue != null)
      {
          string query2 = "select * from Item where SID=@ID";
          SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);
          com1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SID", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
          SqlDataAdapter adp1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
          DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
          adp1.Fill(dt1);
          comboBox3.ValueMember = "ID";
          comboBox3.DisplayMember = "Item";
          comboBox3.DataSource = dt1;
          con.Close();
          comboBox3.Enabled = true;
          comboBox2.Enabled = true;
       }
 }
```

Third ComboBox:

```
private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(comboBox3.SelectedValue);
 }
```

**Note:** I have tried this with Access database. Sql should work with above code. Please let me know if anyone find any problem using this piece of code.
Happy Coding.
Thanks to @vikschool.